# Fragments getting dettached from Tabs when invalidateoptions menu is invoked

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

my application has three tab each tab uses a fragment to display its content. I am using `FragmentPageAdapter` and `ViewPager`. My Second tab fragment have two child fragments. And in the second child fragment i am displaying two more tabs.

```
Tab1             Tab2         Tab3
Fragment1      Fragment2     Fragment3

       ChildFragment1 or ChildFragment2

                         ChildTab1          ChildTab2
                    ChildFragment1    ChildFragment3
```

To elaborate it bit more:

- Tab2 contains Fragment2.
- Inside Fragment2 there is a condition. If condition is true display childFragment1 else display childframent2.
- Inside childfragment2 i am displaying two tabs childtab1 and childtab2
  childtab1 displays childfragment1 and childtab2 displays childfragment3.
- In Fragment2 i am using getchildfragmentmanager().
- In childFragment2 i am again using getchildfragmentmanager and displaying tabs using fragmentTabs.

In my mainactivity i am displaying an `ActionItem` on basis of certain condition. if the codition is true the display actionitem else remove it. To update optionsmenu i am using `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and actionitem show hide logic is implemented in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`:

```
MenuItem alertIcon = menu.findItem(R.id.alertIcon)
if(condtition)
   alertIcon.setVisibility(true);
else
   alertIcon.setVisibility(false);
```

When this code is executed Fragment1 and Fragment3 disappears from the tabs. But the content of Fragment2 is still visible.

I am unable to identify the root cause of this issue, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lots of digging I was able to find out the solution to the above problem. I was calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` from outside of UI thread. So i simply modified the call to:

```
this.runOnUIThread(new Runnable){
   @Override
   public void run(){
       invalidateOptionsMenu();
   }
});
```

The callback which i was receiving in my activity was running into another thread, updating UI from thread other then main caused the problem.